# Xamarin Forms iOS freeze on wake

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

My app (sometimes) freezes on waking from suspension (iOS only). Whether it be waking the phone after locking it for some time, or coming back to the app after running tasks in another app.

Using `Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.X`

Can't debug, because `Visual Studio` disconnects from the device the moment you lock the screen or move the app to the background (home button).

Does anyone else have experience with this behavior?

I've set up stuff in my shared project's `App.xaml.cs` in the `OnSleep` and `OnResume` methods to hopefully handle the issue, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            StorageHelper.SetSleepTime(DateTime.Now);
            StorageHelper.PersistStorage();
            ApiHelper.CurrentAccess.CancelAllRequests();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            var access = ApiHelper.RefreshApiAccess();
            access.UseCredentialGenerator = true;
            var sleepTime = StorageHelper.GetSleepTime();
            if (!sleepTime.HasValue || DateTime.Now.Subtract(sleepTime.Value).TotalMinutes >= MinutesToSleepForReset)
            {
                MainPage = new TransitionNavigationPage(new StartPage());
                StorageHelper.RemoveSleepTime();
            }
            else
            {
                NavigationHelper.UpdateCartItemCount();
            }
        }
```

`SetSleepTime` just stores the time of when the OnSleep method was called, so that if it's been asleep for more than 5 minutes, I can essentially restart the app in the `OnResume`.

Comment: Are any of the API calls you are making in OnResume doing IO?  If so that may be the issue - blocking the UI thread.

Comment: No, no calls or anything. My entire `OnResume` is right there in my post, and all calls are cancelled in `OnSleep`. I've also removed almost every OnAppearing in my app just in case that was the issue. 

That said, it looks like maybe my code is working. I'm working in a team, and it's possible the behavior I was seeing was on a version of the app that didn't have this new code. I tested it this morning, and it seemed to do what I intended.

Comment: Will try again through today/tonight to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking like the answer is just make sure you're not waiting for any api calls to return, and make sure there's nothing blocking the ui thread on `OnResume`. Check for Login in `OnAppearing` methods that may cause this issue.

Mine seems to be resolved by just resetting my app back to my initialization page after 5 minutes. I found somewhere on the internet (can't remember where otherwise I'd post it) that `iOS` allows for your app to continue executing for 10 minutes after sleep (to finish processes). So I think any time after that, it re-allocates the memory for more pressing tasks, causing the app to not have what it needs to continue execution from exactly where it was when it slept.